# Is it possible to show a button when the user logged in on PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi is it possible to hide a button when the user sign out or when the user log in the button will show? I search on google there has much reference about it. Using php?

Comment: The answer is : YES (you asked-- is it possible)

Comment: Thank you is there any script that I can read or a code?

Comment: Check if the user is logged in or not using [if/else](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php) and it should be a piece of cake. We don't know your code so we can't really give you a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using nodejs, you could use express-session: (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_sessions.htm)
There you add information to your session eg. res.locals = {login: true}
Then on the client side you can have the button show either login of logout according to the value.

Another option is to use 'ejs' of 'handlebars' and send along information to your client pages whether they see login or logout. (https://ejs.co) - (https://handlebarsjs.com)

Example for using sessions:
In your routes part you put somethign like this:

```js
//Login user
router.post('/login', redirectHome, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findByCredentials(req.body.email, req.body.password)
        req.session.userId = user._id
        return res.status(200).redirect('/home')
    } catch (e) {
        res.render('login' ,{ title: 'Login', alert:{title: 'Login failed!', type: 'alert-danger', message: e } })
    }
})

router.post('/logout', redirectLogin, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await req.session.destroy()
        await res.clearCookie('sid')
        await res.redirect('/login')
        
    } catch (e) {
        res.render('home', { title:'Home', alert:{ type: 'alert-warning', title:'Unable to logout', message: e}})
    }
})
```

Then your server you add middleware like this:

```js
app.use(async (req, res, next)=> {
    const { userId } = req.session
    if(userId){
        res.locals.user = await User.findOne({_id:userId})
        
    } 
    next()
})
```

Now you can send the info in your route so if on the client side userId is undefined you show login if it has value you show logout.

Hope this helped.